# Sessions sometimes fail in multiple steps form

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I built a form spread on a couple of different pages:

1. Page one: The user fills out his credentials (name, email, tel, etc.)
2. Page two: The data is stored to the database. An account is created and the user is automatically logged in.
3. Page three: The user has to be logged in to continue.
   // etc

About 24 out of 25 times all goes well, but for some reason, it fails 1/25. I can sometimes reproduce it, but most of the times not.

On step 2 i use this code:

```
$hash = md5($salt.time()); // Salt is unique, time is "extra".
$_SESSION["hash"] = $hash; // Session stored
setcookie("code",$hash, time()+2440); // Cookie for backup
// $hash is stored in the database
```

On step 3 i try to read it using:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '28800');
include("../database.inc.php"); // Needed for DB connection
include("functies.inc.php"); // Needed for filtering vars (also sessions)
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
$sessionshash = $_SESSION["hash"];
$cookiehash = filter($_COOKIE["hash"]);
// $hash is fetched from the database
```

The results approx 1 out of 25 times: $sessionhash and $cookiehash are exactly the same. While $hash from the database is different. Very rarely sometimes all three are different or sometimes one or the other isn't set.

I can't debug it, because it seems random behaviour. Any has suggestions how to debug?

Comment: you store $hash in session and $hashcode in cookie. Are they the same? what does filter() do?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's both $hash, I simplified the code in my startpost. Filter is a custom filter which cleans sessions / posts / gets / cookies in order to prevent attacks. Besides that I ofcoarse use prepared statements and stored procedures to prevent SQL-injection and things like that.

Comment: How do you pass from one page to next page? Are you using ajax? If so, review the async effect.

Comment: I used ajax on each page, but not in between pages. So step 1, step 2 and step 3 al are real pages such as page1.php, page2.php and page3.php